# How to run wine in Docker image as host user?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, wine

I have a Docker container that I'm trying to run a .exe in via Wine. However, in order to keep the output files from the .exe (and other file processing being done in the container), I'm running my Docker image with my host system ID via

```
docker run -it -u $(id -u):$(id -g)
```

However, wine won't let me run anything because "`<dir>/.wine does not belong to you` since the container and all the files in it belong to `root`.

I've tried changing ownership of the `WINEPREFIX` location, but that hasn't worked and attempting to set the `WINEPREFIX` to somewhere that both the host user and the container root would have access to led to other problems.

I know that I *can* just run the image without using my host ID, but that would create problems later on in my pipeline since the files outputted from the container would still belong to "`root`"

Relevant Dockerfile below (some of it is superfluous from me attempting other solutions):

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ENV CWD=/workdir
ENV IMAGES=/images
ENV OUTPUT=/output
ENV WINEPREFIX=/workdir/.wine

ARG USER_ID
ARG GROUP_ID

WORKDIR ${CWD}

COPY files/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN mkdir ${IMAGES} && \
    mkdir ${OUTPUT} && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends file \
       p7zip-full \
       wine \
       python3 && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Attempt at adding a user with the same uid/groupid as host
RUN groupadd -g ${GROUP_ID} myuser && \
    useradd -l -u ${USER_ID} -g myuser myuser && \
    chown -R -c ${USER_ID}:${GROUP_ID} /workdir
COPY other-files
COPY entrypoint files

ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
```

Built with the following:

```
docker build --build-arg USER_ID=$(id -u) \
    --build-arg GROUP_ID=$(id -g) \
    -t my-tag
```

The `chown` doesn't appear to actually change ownership to the supplied ID.

### Update to add additional attempts at solution

I even attempted to make a distinct directory through the Dockerfile and then change the permissions there but that also didn't work (changes bolded)

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ENV CWD=/workdir
ENV IMAGES=/images
ENV OUTPUT=/output
**ENV WINEPREFIX=/winedir/.wine**

ARG USER_ID
ARG GROUP_ID

WORKDIR ${CWD}

COPY files/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN mkdir ${IMAGES} && \
    mkdir ${OUTPUT} && \
    **mkdir /winedir**
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends file \
       p7zip-full \
       wine \
       python3 && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Attempt at adding a user with the same uid/groupid as host
RUN groupadd -g ${GROUP_ID} myuser && \
    useradd -l -u ${USER_ID} -g myuser myuser && \
    chown -R -c ${USER_ID}:${GROUP_ID} **/winedir**
COPY other-files
COPY entrypoint files

...
```

Comment: This works for me to change the permissions when I add the missing `&& \` to one of the lines so it will run. Is /workdir a volume?

Comment: Oops, I typed the code in by hand here (copying from another system) so in the actual code, there is a ` && \ ` on the line before the `chown`. And no, /workdir is not a volume, it's just a directory created in the container.

Comment: If you run `ls -ldn /workdir` inside the container, do the user and group numbers match the user ID and group ID that you're trying to run as?

Comment: No, it says that `/workdir` belong to 0 0

Comment: Did you also change `${USER_ID}:{GROUP_ID}` to `${USER_ID}:${GROUP_ID}` ? I had to do that to get it to work.

Comment: Yes, that was also a typo when copying the code for the post - actual code has that